# How to add cookies with a request in proxy server before forwarding to origin?

Tags: apache, nginx, proxy, webserver, nginx-reverse-proxy

I want to share access to a website e.g abc.com which is protected with login. I don't want to share passwords so I want to add cookies to the request using a proxy server. After some research I found that we can use ngix or apache to proxy forword requests.

But now I need guidance or a tutorial how to set things up on a apache or ngix server